# PHP: Printing assosiative array into another array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to print an assosiative array inside another array.

Here is the code :

"$posted_fields", is an assosiative array composed of multiple arrays, each array contains the data of a posted field. The syntax is like so: my posted field(checkboxes) = array('key'=>'THE NAME OF THE FIELD', 'value'=>'array(FIELD VALUES)', ...).

The Loop is like so:

```
$posted_fields = array();
foreach($post_values as $field_name => $field_value){


           $posted_fields[] = array('key'   => $field_name,
             'value' => $field_value,
             'compare' => 'IN',
            );



}
```

I get the following result:

```
$posted_fields = array(
                    array
                    (
                        "key" => "property_country",
                        "value" => array
                            (
                                "es",
                                "fr",
                                "ca",
                            ),

                        "compare" => "IN"
                    ),array
                    (
                        "key" => "property_city",
                        "value" => array
                            (
                                "montreal"
                            ),

                        "compare" => "IN"
                    )

            );
```

Here is what i want to do:

"$args" is the assosiative array where i want to print the "$posted_field" result.

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page ' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'property',
            'post_status' => 'publish',             
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relationship' => 'AND',

                $posted_fields  

            ),
            'fields' => 'ids',
        );
```

Instead of having this

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page ' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'property',
            'post_status' => 'publish',             
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relationship' => 'AND',
                array(
                    array
                    (
                        "key" => "property_country",
                        "value" => array
                            (
                                "es",
                                "fr",
                                "ca",
                            ),

                        "compare" => "IN"
                    ),array
                    (
                        "key" => "property_city",
                        "value" => array
                            (
                                "montreal"
                            ),

                        "compare" => "IN"
                    )

                )
            ),
            'fields' => 'ids',
        );
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page ' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'property',
            'post_status' => 'publish',             
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relationship' => 'AND',

                    array
                    (
                        "key" => "property_country",
                        "value" => array
                            (
                                "es",
                                "fr",
                                "ca",
                            ),

                        "compare" => "IN"
                    ),array
                    (
                        "key" => "property_city",
                        "value" => array
                            (
                                "montreal"
                            ),

                        "compare" => "IN"
                    )

                ),

            'fields' => 'ids',
        );
```

The Difference here is after ['relationship' => 'AND',]. 
I want to have `['relationship' => 'AND', array(), array(), ...] and not ['relationship' => 'AND', array( array(), array(), ...]

I hope the message is clear

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get closer to the solution. I've previously used the function below to expand multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$input_size = (count($multidim_array));
for($row = 0; $row < $input_size; $row++ )
    {
    echo "the row number $row<br>";

        foreach($multidim_array[$row] as $key => $value)
        {
            echo "key $key, value $value<br>";
        }
    }
```